# Bulk append URL (add word to slug)

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, mysql, urls, slug

Is there a way to bulk add one word at the end of each URL for posts? I have around 3500 posts and it would be time consuming to add to each one.

For example URL's are

```
www.example.com/my-post/
www.examle.com/new-post/
```

And I want to add one word to end of URL

```
www.example.com/my-post-word/
www.examle.com/new-post-word/
```

Is there MySql script to do such thing?

Comment: This could be done with multiple ways. 1) Wordpress Loop 2) SQL like `UPDATE wp_posts  SET post_name = CONCAT(post_name,'-word') where post_type='post'` You can add ADD more types for filtering. BUT TAKE A BACKUP FIRST!!!!^inf

Comment: This solution also worked :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code:

```
if ( isset($_GET['slug-update']) ) {

    $posts = get_posts();

    foreach($posts as $singlepost) {
        if($singlepost->post_status === 'publish'){
            $post_id = $singlepost->ID;
            $current_slug = $singlepost->post_name;
            $updated_slug = $current_slug . '-word';
        }

        wp_update_post( array(
            'ID' => $post_id,
            'post_name' => $updated_slug ) );
    }

    die('Slug Updated');    
}
```

Add this to your theme's function.php. Then run this with `www.example.com/?slug-update`

P.S. this will only update the default post type 'post' (backup the database to be secure)

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: I'd recommend putting this into a wpcli command instead of the functions.php.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just add it inside the WP admin [permalink settings](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen)?
[image]